# How to create a 3D array in Python with Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a 2x2x3 three-dimensional array in Python.

I did the following:

`x = numpy.array([[[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]], [[1,1], [1,1], [1,1]]])`

However, my output is a 2x3x2 array.

```
print(x.shape)
```

What did I wrong? And can anyone please explain step by step how to build a 3D array, I am a bit confused about the rows, colums and axis.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you do `numpy.zeros((2,2,3))` you will see what an array of the desired shape (filled with zeros, obviously) looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you want

```
x = np.array([[[1,1,2], [2,3,3]], [[1,1,1], [1,1,1]]])
print(x.shape)
print(x)
```

Refer to this [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) for explanation.

What you created was an array with 3 rows, 2 columns and say 2 frames so you didn't get what you wanted (2 rows & 3 columns). We can make a 3d array representation as `(frames, rows, columns)`.

Further you could've created an array with dimensions `(n,)` using

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Then you can reshape it as per the requirement

For `2x2x3` you could do

```
x = x.reshape(2,2,3)
```

Similarly for `2x3x2`

```
x = x.reshape(2,3,2)
```

Comment: This works :), Can you maybe explain your solution further? Or do you have tips/sources that explains this?

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html @tom

Comment: @Tom I've made edit with an explanation. Hope it helps!